# C++ Copy Constructor and Assignment Operator

Tags: c++

I am creating a stack with the following Attributes and I am trying to create a copy-constructor and an assignment-operator but I can't since the new object and the old one point to the same memory. Please assist.

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node(const T& data, Node* n = 0)
    {
        element = data;
        next = n;
    }

    T element;
    Node* next;
};

/* The top of the stack */
Node* top;
```

Comment: Check "[What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)"

Answer (score 0):

For copy constructor do it like

```
Node(const Node& data)
{
    element = data.element;
    next=new Node();
    *next = *data.next;
}
```

Comment: non-exception safe: blows up if `new` or `Node()` throws

Comment: Thanks man, my problem was in main.cpp, I was suppose to to say Stack<T>* newStack = new Stack<T>(*oldStack);

Comment: Np. but copy constructor is like this

Answer (score 0):

Assignment Operator :

```
Node& operator=(const Node& data) {
    if (this != &other) { // to avoid self-assignment
        element = data.element;

        // allocate new memory
        Node* tmp = new Node();
        std::memcpy(tmp, data.next, sizeof(Node));

        // deallocate old memory
        delete next;

        // assign new memory to object
        next = new Node();
        std::memcpy(next, tmp, sizeof(Node));
    }
    return *this; 
}
```

Exception safety is taken into consideration.